# Topology of Distribution via limit of topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-topology, geometric-topology

As far as I know, we can define the topology of distribution (either on T or on noncompact nonempty set $\Omega$ ). I read one note and find we can also see the topology as one type of limit. Can anyone explain more about this?

For example $C^{\infty}(T)=\cap_{k} C^{k}(T)$ [for more detailed reference, see this](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/real/notes_2019-20/08d_functions_on_circles.pdf). How to define topology from a limit viewpoint? I know the another way to define topology of distribution from Rudin's Functional analysis. But I find it hard to understand this viewpoint.

I would also know more literature about analysis on T or $T^{n}$.

Comment: Somewhere in those notes there is a construction/description of the "limit" topology as a subspace of the product topology, which is probably more familiar. There is not a systematic literature emphasizing tori or multi-tori, but there is the obvious pedagogical advantage of compactness and relatively explicit spectral decompositions, which was my motivation. The colimit topology on distributions on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^n$ is not as easily described explicitly, thought to say "colimit..." does make the point that there's at most one (up to unique isomorphism), _if_ it exists at all...

Comment: Thanks, I get this point view now although didn't check everything in existence proof. This is really different from Rudin's introduction. The colim is more like building a new theory with some goals of continuity. But what Rudin did is introduce explicitly what is topology and all things following are properties or proposition.

Comment: Right: Rudin did what was usual at that time, namely, to construct something and prove that it has certain properties... rather than specify those properties in advance and ask about existence.